# Apply product and chain rule to differentiate with respect to one variable

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, chain-rule

I have the following:

$$
u = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4t}} \phi\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)
$$

I need to find $u_t$
This equation was found by solving the characteristic equation:
$$
\frac{dx}{xt} = \frac{dt}{t^2} = \frac{du}{-\left(\frac{1}{4}x^2 + \frac{1}{2}t\right)u}
$$

solving the equation from the first two yields:
$$
r = \frac{x}{t}
$$

solving from the second two yields:
$$
v = u\sqrt{t}e^{\frac{x^2}{4t}}
$$

we let $v = \phi(r)$
this gives us:
$$
u\sqrt{t}e^{\frac{x^2}{4t}} = \phi\left(\frac{x}{t}\right)
$$

that is where the equation for $u$ comes from.

Here is what I have:

\begin{align}
u_t & = \frac{-1}{2t^{\frac{3}{2}}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4t}}\phi\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) + \frac{x^2}{4t^2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^\frac{-x^2}{4t}\phi\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) + \left( \frac{-x}{t^2} \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4t}}\phi'\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) \\
&  = \frac{-u}{2t} + \frac{x^2u}{4t^2} - \left( \frac{x}{t^2} \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4t}}\phi'\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) \\ 
\end{align}

However the solution given has:

$$
u_t = \frac{-u}{2t} + \frac{x^2u}{4t^2} - \phi'\left( \frac{x}{t} \right) \left(\frac{xu}{t^2}\right)
$$

I can't figure out what I am doing wrong before I look at $u_{xx}$ (I already tried that and again, am making the same mistake).

Comment: Appart from two errata you typed ($4t²$ not $4t$ in first line and $x/t²$ not $-x/t²$ in second line) I think the given solution lacks $.../ \;\phi \left( \frac{x}{t} \right)$ at the end.

Comment: Thanks I corrected the typo,

Comment: I am going to add more background to where the equation comes from.  Perhaps there is a calculation somewhere that would eliminate the division by $\phi\left( \frac{x}{t}\right)$

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is in the second term. It should be
$$\frac{x^2}{4t^{2}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}}e^{\frac{-x^2}{4t}}\phi\left(\frac{x}{t}\right) = \frac{x^2}{4t^{2}}u$$
You just forgot the chain rule.

Comment: I think the OP type wrongly (missed squaring $t$), because in the second line he writes correctly $\frac{x^2}{4t^{2}}u$